# @ for handling assets in vue js not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to set address of my photos from src folder and based on vue doc i have to use @ . the problem is when i use it jetbrains underline the address with red line and also my page not compile anymore the error is:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@/assets/image/background.png' in '/home/sina/WebstormProjects/landing-vue/src' @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 7:749-791 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue @ ./src/App.vue @ ./src/main.js @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

and also this is the css:

```
background: url("@/assets/image/background.png");
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be just `url(~assets/image/background.png)`?

Comment: @Samurai8 nothing changed

Answer (score 16):

try this:
    `background: url("~@/assets/image/background.png")`

Comment: Everything else didn't work for me, you saved my day!! :-)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. @sepehr

Answer (score 1):

I see in the error message: `Error: Can't resolve './@/assets/image/background.png'`; which means that the url `./@/assets/image/background.png` is probably wrong.

Try replacing in your source code `./@/assets/image/background.png` by `@/assets/image/background.png`

Comment: This worked but i had to add ~, so url was `~@/assets/image/...` in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`@` is nothing to do with `vue` per-se but it more to do with Webpack. It's an alias to a path so that alias is probably missing and in turn it can't find your file in that path since `@` won't be a valid folder.